# 2 equations — please explain

Tags: analysis

I have 2 equations that come together to form a graph.

[image: graph of atmospheres]

The first (purple area) equation used to form the graph is $p_e = 5e^{-altitude/7000}$, and the second equation for the blue area is $p_k = 1\text{atm}\cdot e^{-altitude/5000}$.

Could you please explain to me what these equations mean and how they relate to each other on the graph.

Thanks in advance.

REFERENCES: http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Kerbin
and http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Eve

Comment: Please add more details. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I can't even see the graph...

Comment: Sorry pressed enter accidentally. Will update ASAP

Comment: for a quick reference i am trying to understand the chart on http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Eve but i am not sure how to implement the equation

Comment: Now I see the chart, yet I can't see the functions...oh, well.

Comment: If $a$ is the altitude in metres then $P_{\text{Kerbin}}= \exp(-a/5000)$ and  $P_{\text{Eve}}= 5\exp(-a/7000)$

Comment: Functions finally!

Comment: This simply tells you that the pressure on Eve is much higher than on Kerbin if you consider it at the same altitude. The formulas give you the pressure for each planet depending on the altitude.

Answer (score 1):

They just reported on the same plot the pressure as a function of the altitude. The upper curve is for Kerbin, the lower is for Eve. For sure, they have produced two separate graphs but, in this form, you really see how pressures compare for the same altitude on both planets.